# Why is 'EDITBIN /STACK:2097152 w3wp.exe' cmd is giving me an LNK1342 error?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis, stack

I am trying to increase stack size, but keep getting this error after running

```
EDITBIN /STACK:2097152 w3wp.exe
```

'*fatal error LNK1342: failed to save a backup copy of the binary file to be edited*'

I am not able to find anything about correcting this online.

I am using vs dev tools 2022, windows server 2019, iis 10

Comment: Why are you trying to do this, why do you need a larger stack?

Comment: Microsoft only supports such binaries (`w3wp.exe`) in their original form, not manipulated in any way (unless you find an official document from Microsoft that says you can). Don't ever modify the system files like this, or you will be in big trouble afterwards.